# Borderlands 3 red chests loot pool

Tags: borderlands-3

With the current event in Borderlands 3 "Rare Chest Riches" the drop rate of legendary items did increase drastically for red chests. Now I am wondering about the loot pool they draw from.

**Can a red chest drop weapons like the Redistributor as it has a dedicated drop location? Or can red chests only drop world drop loot?**